# How to populate a DIV after MySQL update with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm developing an AJAX project using jQuery. I'm thinking of creating a page that displays data from a table. On this page, I want to put a form to add another row to this table.

The problem is that I want to update the table on my page as soon as I have submitted the new data. Is that even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is bind an event to the submit button for the form.

```
$('#formbutton').click(submit);
```

Then load the values from the fields in the submit() function and then use $.ajax to submit the POST request and define a success call function to do a GET ajax request

```
function submit(){
  var field1 = $('#field1').val();
  var field2 = $('#field2').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'submitform.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data {field1: field1, field2, field2},
    success: function(data){
      getData();
    }

  });

}

function getData(){
  $.get("table.php",function(data){
    $('#table').html(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You make the AJAX request to your script.

Your script does its work and returns the new data.

Your AJAX query's success handler function updates the page with the received data.AJ

Just look at the examples in the jquery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery ajax to send the form results to a PHP script, get the PHP to update/insert to the mysql db, then get the PHP to echo out the table data to the jQuery success callback, in which you take received data and place it in a div/table!

To get you started:

http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/send-html-form-results-in-an-email-from-php-using-jquery-ajax/